# How To Post a Photo To Facebook Using PHP using Latest API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to update a facebook stats along with the photo.When i tried to update the stats without image it worked successfully but it fails when i add image URL.

```
$request = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array(
  'message' => 'I love articles on benmarshall.me!',


)))->execute();

$response = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

The following codes return no errors but fails to upload the photo to facebook

```
$request = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/me/photos', array(
  'message' => 'I love articles on benmarshall.me!',
      'source' => 'http://domain.online/demo/1.jpg',


)))->execute();

$response = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

I also tried the following code but it return error 500.

```
require_once( 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php' );

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$data = [
  'message' => 'My awesome photo upload example.',
  'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('/path/to/photo.jpg'),
];

try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
  $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data, '{access-token}');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
```

Comment: check your error logs. you need to learn how to debug php.

Comment: i am new to centos webpanel cud you tell where i can find the error logs

Comment: google for "centos error logs" and you will find a lot of helpful articles.